# Message Type field in social post not appearing

Tags: socialpost

IN the message type from the social post below, am getting any picklist values, As  checked its a standard picklist field , but may anyone please suggest why no values are showing in the field and how to get the values? thanks

[image]

Comment: I have the same problem. I cannot see any picklist values on Message type as well as Managed Social Account. I've already set the Field level security, but I still can't see. Any idea? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The social action is created when you install Social Customer Service. You can add, remove, and organize fields to suit your organization.
https://support.salesforce.com/articleView?id=social_customer_service_custom_pub.htm&type=0&language=en_US

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I managed to do this as below.

I went to the " Social post Field level Decurity for profile and activated the field and the message type reappear.